# Concatenate string and dynamic id in event handler

Tags: javascript, meteor, concatenation

I have a Meteor template with a dropdown menu that returns a string that is then used in a method.  Since I am selecting the value of the target using the class of the dropdown, this will only work for the first instance of the template - after that, other templates use the selected value from the first template.

How can I instead reference the id of the dropdown menu to make sure I am pointing to the right instance?  The id is `build{{this._id}}` and I cannot figure out the syntax to use in the event handler.  I tried:

`var selection = $("'#' + 'build' + 'buildId' option:selected).val();`

but no luck.

```
<template name="Build">
    <form>
        <select class="form-control build-comps" id="build{{buildId}}">
            {{#each comps}}
                <option class="comp" value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
                <option class="comp" value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
                <option class="comp" value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
    </form>
</template>

Template.Build.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var buildId = this._id;
        var selection = $(".build-comps option:selected").val();
        ...
    }
});
```

UPDATE WITH CODE:

```
var selection = $('#build' + buildId + " " + 'option:selected');
```

Comment: It looks like you may be missing a quote, or have one too many in your selector: ```$('#build' + buildId)```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.  And can handlebars be used in Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I initially though the script was a part of the template tag (in which case handlebars would be recognized). However, since it is a part of the events logic you will not be able to use handlebars. Edited original response.

Comment: By itself, that returns no errors, but it doesn't work when I include `option: selected`.  As in `var selection = $("'#build' + buildId option:selected").val();`  The error is: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#build' + buildId option:selected`

Comment: $('#build' + buildId + ' option:selected')

Comment: Thanks so much - I added the final code as an resolved update.  Needed to add `+ " "` to separate the last part.